# Express.js serve files from directory about project root

Tags: node.js, file, express, static, serve

I would like to break my node.js/express.js  UI (html/resources) out of my existing project directory.  IOW,  I want to move all of my static 
 html/js/css..etc into an external directory, above my project directory.
Example:

```
rootpath  
   /UI_1  
     Views ( html files)  
       index.html  
     public
        javascripts  
          status.js  


  /NodeJSProject (has express...etc
```

I am able to serve the html files just fine.  However,  I am having trouble getting the static resources (js/css..etc) served correctly,  or referenced correctly by the html files...

in my node project, in app.js  I tired this...

```
app.use('cust1', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../UI_1/public")));
```

and then in the html...

```
 <script src="cust1/javascripts/status.js"></script>
```

Is this even possible??,  thanks .

Answer (score -1):

If `/NodeJSProject` is at the same directory level as `/UI_1`, then it should work if you add a `/` to the path in the script tag and remove `/cust1` which isn't anywhere in your static directory hierarchy:

```
<script src="/javascripts/status.js"></script>
```

And, change the middleware to this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../UI_1/public")));
```

That will make the path that the browser requests absolute rather than relative to where the host HTML page is.  When you leave off the leading `/`, then the browser uses the path of the containing HTML file which may or may not be what you want.  When you use a `/` on it, then nothing is relative to the path of the containing HTML file and it's a lot easier to be consistent about what will be requested so you can match it up with `express.static()`.

I have no idea why "cust1" was in your `app.use()` statement because you show no `cust1` anywhere in the static resources so I recommended you remove it.  If you think that needs to be there, then please explain what it is for and why?

---

You could also have `cust1` in both paths/URLs with the leading `/`:

```
<script src="/cust1/javascripts/status.js"></script>
```

and

```
app.use(express.static("/cust1", path.join(__dirname, "../UI_1/public")));
```

But, it does not seem to be required.  If there's a `cust2`, then you'd have to customize everything for each customer and have separate middleware for each customer.